How do I render different components in react Portal?
I am working on a project that requires  filing multiple forms, and some of the forms are not compulsory, so I have to render them as modals upon button click. i  am working with nextjs14 and I wasn't able to create a parallel route modal, instead am using react portal.
here is my code for a component that needs to render three modals, however, it keeps rendering one whenever you click any of the buttons.
import { useState } from "react";
import Associating from "./Associating";
import Triggers from "./Triggers";
import Relievers from "./Relievers";
import Modal from "@/components/Modal";
import {
  useAddAssocMutation,
  useAddCharMutation,
  useAddTriggerMutation,
  useAddRelieverMutation,
} from "@/services/apiSlice";
import { ManagedUI } from "@/components/ManagedUi";

const Character = () => {
  const [onset, setOnset] = useState("");
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState("");
  const [af, setAf] = useState("");
  const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState("");
  const [severity, setSeverity] = useState("");
  const [timing, setTiming] = useState("");
  const [relievers, setRelievers] = useState([]);
  const [assoc, setAssoc] = useState([]);
  const [triggers, setTriggers] = useState([]);
  const hpc_id = 3;
  const [addChar, { data, isSuccess, isError, error }] = useAddCharMutation();
  const [addAssoc] = useAddAssocMutation();
  const [addTrigger] = useAddTriggerMutation();
  const [addReliever] = useAddRelieverMutation();
  const [char_id, setChar_id] = useState(0);
  const { setOpenModal, setKey } = useContext(ManagedUI);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const char = {
      onset: onset,
      duration: duration,
      timing: timing,
      frequency: frequency,
      severity: severity,
      agg_fac: af,
      associations: assoc,
      triggers: triggers,
      rel_factors: relievers,
    };

    addChar({ hpc_id, char });
    if (isSuccess) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.id);
      setChar_id(data.id);
    }

    if (isError) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    function postOthers() {
      if (char_id != 0 || NaN) {
        assoc.forEach((el) => {
          addAssoc({ character_id: char_id, assoc: el });
          console.log(el);
        });
        triggers.forEach((trig) => {
          addTrigger({ character_id: char_id, trigger: trig });
          console.log(trig);
        });
        relievers.forEach((relv) => {
          addReliever({ character_id: char_id, relievers: relv });
        });
      } else if (char_id == 0 || undefined || NaN) {
        console.log("Append a Character Id!");
      }
    }
    setTimeout(postOthers(), 3000);
  }, [char_id]);
  return (
    <div>
      <legend className="big-head">Characterise Your Symptom</legend>
      <div className="form-div">
        <label className="label-p" for="onset">
          Onset:
        </label>
        <input
          className="input"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setOnset(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-div">
        <label className="label-p" for="duration">
          Duration
        </label>
        <input
          className="input"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setDuration(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-div">
        <label className="label-p" for="freq">
          Frequency
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="input"
          onChange={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setFrequency(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-div">
        <label className="label-p" for="timing">
          Is your symptom worse at any time of the day? When?
        </label>
        <input
          className="input"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setTiming(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-div">
        <label className="label-p" for="af">
          Aggravating Factors:
        </label>
        <input
          className="input"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setAf(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-div">
        <label className="label-p" for="severity">
          Severity:
        </label>
        <input
          className="input"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setSeverity(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Any Associating Factors</p>
        <button
          className="fine-btn"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setKey("assoc");
            setOpenModal(true);
          }}
        >
          Add Associating Factors
        </button>

        <Modal>
          <button onClick={() => setOpenModal(false)}>x</button>
          <Associating setAssoc={setAssoc} char_id={char_id} />
        </Modal>
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>If there are any Triggers you might need to include them</p>
        <button
          className="fine-btn"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setKey("trigger");
            setOpenModal(true);
          }}
        >
          Add Triggers
        </button>
        <Modal>
          <button onClick={() => setOpenModal(false)}>x</button>
          <Triggers setTriggers={setTriggers} char_id={char_id} />
        </Modal>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Add Rlieving Factors</p>
        <button
          className="fine-btn"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setOpenModal(true);
            setKey("relievers");
          }}
        >
          Add Relieving Factors
        </button>
        <Modal>
          <button onClick={() => setOpenModal(false)}>x</button>
          <Relievers setRelievers={setRelievers} char_id={char_id} />
        </Modal>
      </div>

      <button className="fine-btn" type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Save Your Character
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Character;

notice there are three modal wrapped component  in this character component, however anytime a button is clicked only one of them will show. for all three separate buttons regardless of the component wrapped inside the modal.
here is my modal wrapper
     import { useState, useRef, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import { ManagedUI } from "./ManagedUi";
export default function Modal({ children }) {
  const { setOpenModal, openModal } = useContext(ManagedUI);
  const { key } = useContext(ManagedUI);
  const modalRef = useRef();
  const [domReady, setDomready] = useState(false);
  const closeModal = (e) => {
    if (modalRef.current === e.target) {
      setOpenModal(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setDomready(true);
  }, [key]);
  if (!openModal) {
    return null;
  }
  return domReady
    ? createPortal(
        <div
          className="dialog dialog-open"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            closeModal(e);
          }}
          ref={modalRef}
        >
          <div className="cont-dialog col-div">
            <div id={key}>{children}</div>
          </div>
        </div>,
        document.getElementById("modal-root"),
        key
      )
    : null;
}

"use client";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
export const ManagedUI = createContext(undefined);

export function ManagedUIProvider({ children }) {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [key, setKey] = useState("");
  return (
    <ManagedUI.Provider value={{ openModal, setOpenModal, key, setKey }}>
      {children}
    </ManagedUI.Provider>
  );
}

my layout component
import "./globals.css";
import "./styles.css";
import StoreProvider from "./StoreProvider";
import { ManagedUIProvider } from "@/components/ManagedUi";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <StoreProvider>
      <ManagedUIProvider>
        <html lang="en">
          <body>
            <div id="modal-root"></div>
            {children}
          </body>
        </html>
      </ManagedUIProvider>
    </StoreProvider>
  );
}

everything about the project is working except this aberrant behavior with the modal
